# how to make the eclipse IDE to be compatible for PIC devices?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplab, eclipse

I am looking for a PIC development environment that is better than MPLab.  Is it possible to to install and configure Eclipse to work with PIC microcontrollers?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.  Long answer: It's complicated.  How bad do you want this? If it's personal preference for a small project, stick with MPLab.  If you want to develop, maintain and distribute the tool, that's a different story, and the question is better suited for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

[Microchip MPLAB X](http://www.microchip.com/en_US/family/mplabx/index.html) is in Beta, and soon to be released. It is based on NetBeans, similar to Eclipse, and is available for Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. It supports all Microchip microcontrollers, including the PIC32. There are free versions of compilers available for download for 8-bit, 16-bit and 32-bit MCUs. It is a big improvement over MPLAB 8 and works well on Mac and Linux, not just Windows.

Comment: It's been in beta for a long time... ;(

Comment: Saw it demoed at ESC Chicago 2011. Didn't get a specific release date, but I would guess it will be released by MASTERS 2011 in August.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it but http://sourceforge.net/projects/piccbuilder/ may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Visual Studio eg VC++ Express (free) as an editor but not as a debugger, as [others have done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762268/free-alternative-to-mplab-pic-development). (Some other alternatives at that link).